# Firebase Angular9

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I cant display particular element from db.

```js
//component.html
<section class="firee">
    <figure class="snip1208">
        <div  *ngFor="let scholarship of scholarships" >
        <h3>{{scholarship.title}}</h3>
        <p>{{scholarship.description}}</p>
        </div>
    </figure>
</section>
//component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFireDatabase} from 'angularfire2/database';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-scholarship',
    templateUrl: './scholarship.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./scholarship.component.css']
})
export class ScholarshipComponent implements OnInit {
    scholarships: any[];
    constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase){
    db.list('scholarships')
        .valueChanges()
        .subscribe(scholarships => {
        this.scholarships = scholarships;
        console.log(this.scholarships); });
    }
    ngOnInit(): void {
    }
}
```

that's work

but when I put, for example

```html
<div *ngFor="let scholarship of scholarships" >
    <h3>{{scholarship.3}}</h3>
</div>
```

that doesn't work. I've tried also with "first_post", but also doesn't work

here is db[image]

Comment: Do you see `[object Object]` rendered?

Comment: If i put       
<div  *ngFor="let scholarship of scholarships" >
        <h3>{{scholarship}}</h3>
      </div>
yes

but with .title and .description rendered all context form db

Comment: So you are able to render the properties? Could you please say what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I can't render one block from db.
For example  only 3.title(u can see on screenshot)

Comment: Remove the `*ngFor` and render them directly. Try: `<h3>{{scholarships?.3}}</h3>`. Remove the enclosing `div` tag.

Comment: Does not work :(

Comment: Please post more of the HTML.

Comment: For this page, I don't have more

Comment: Could you please post a screenshot of `console.log(this.scholarships)`?

Comment: Thank you 
With <h3>{{scholarship[3].title}}</h3> that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might need:

```
<h3>{{scholarship[3].title}}</h3>
```

Or

```
<h3>{{scholarship["3"].title}}</h3>
```